# Get output in php

Tags: php, json

In PHP, I have this code.

```html
echo $response;
//output is 
//[[1,"PROMO"],[24761,"TRANS"]]
```

I want to retrieve 24761. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried something? have you tried searching parsing json response via PHP? if not, then if you tried, you will easily get a result.

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting the `json` response you need to `decode` it

```
$arr  = '[[1,"PROMO"],[24761,"TRANS"]]';
$decode_json = json_decode($arr);
echo $decode_json[1][0];
```

Comment: Sir, var_dump($response) output is "string(29) "[[1,"PROMO"],[24761,"TRANS"]]""  i.e., it is string so how can i retrieve this?

Comment: That's great. Please mark my answer useful so others can also find it helpful.